# logging not working in liquibase 3.6.1 using loglevel=debug

Tags: liquibase

I have used `--logLevel=debug` from command line with `liquibase 3.6.1` and I don't see any debug output being generated. Has anyone used `3.6.1` and got this working?

Below is the output I get after executing liquibase command.

```
Starting Liquibase at Tue, 03 Jul 2018 14:07:10 EDT (version 3.6.1 built at 2018-04-11 08:41:04)
Liquibase: Update has been successful.
```

Comment: Same issue for me.

Comment: Also, adding --logFile doesn't help.

Comment: Is there an alternative to liquibase that anyone can recommend?  This kind of thing seems really lame - not being able to see debug or info output.

Answer (score 4):

The issue has been reported https://liquibase.jira.com/browse/CORE-3220 and there's a pending PR for the fix: https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/pull/770

Answer (score 1):

Right now you can downgrade the liquibase core version to `3.5.5`, it will resolve the issue, I had faced the same issue, after downgrading version to 3.5.5 the issue was resolved.