# Liquibase 3.6.2 logLevel=debug not honored?

Tags: logback, slf4j, liquibase

It seems that liquibase 3.6.2 does not honor the debug flag (--logLevel=debug).
I have all the required dependencies and everything works OK but it is in "super-silent" mode.
 
I can not see on the console which changesets have been executed/applied (which I could in liquibase 3.5.3).
Am I doing something wrong?

Or is it just that liquibase does not work well with slf4j yet?
https://liquibase.jira.com/browse/CORE-2389 - will be fixed in version 4.0.
To the liquibase team: Does that mean that there will be no debug logging on the console untill then?

My classpath/dependencies:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
    <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.6.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle.jdbc</groupId>
    <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
    <version>${oracle.ojdbc.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.yaml</groupId>
    <artifactId>snakeyaml</artifactId>
    <version>1.23</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.25</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
    <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: same for me: after update from liquibase 3.6.1 to 3.6.2 (due to Spring Boot upgrade to 2.1) the --logLevel=debug command line parameter doesn't lead to more verbose output.

Comment: It seems to be the same bug as in 3.6.1: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51161022/logging-not-working-in-liquibase-3-6-1-using-loglevel-debug